# Custom Navigation - Shop By Brand

Tags: magento

Is it possible to dynamically populate a "shop by brand" drop down in the navigation menu.  I am trying to avoid manually adding each brand as a subcategory.

We are running the latest version of magento enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a few ways you can do this:

1) Use a module such as [FME Shop by Brand](http://www.fmeextensions.com/shop-by-manufacturers.html)

2) You can do it manually doing the following steps:

- create an attribute for your products called "brand"
- load your product collection
- loop through each item and grab the brand, and place it in to an array
- remove duplicates from the array (now you have a list of brands)
- create pragmatically cms pages for each brand
- show in each cms page only products with that brand

The downside of the second approach is that it takes a lot of time (compared with the relative cheap cost of a shop by brand module)

Comment: Thanks for the info, the extension is so cheap I'm probably going to go with that.